# Slow performance with Phonegap (Cordova) for windows phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, cross-platform

Currently in our company we have this app written in ***Phonegap (Cordova)*** framework for **Android** and **iOS** platform. Everything works perfect and fast. Now we decided that we want to cover **Windows Phone** devices too. I noticed that app is performing very slow (like really slow...) on windows phone platform (emulator & actual device). If request to our server with ajax, parsing data and rendering on screen needs 2 seconds on Android or iOS, on Windows Phone it is like 10 seconds. Do you have any idea why is this happening? Do I need to enable hardware acceleration like I did on Android? I don't know much about Windows Phone development and I would like to get some help here.

Comment: I'm curious if you ever found any performance improvements for wp? I'm using cordova with ionic and am experincing the same things you describe. So far I've only been able to improve scrolling by disabling ionics js scrolling implementation.

Comment: @asprotte Hei :) No. But here is my question on reddit and there was feedback with some WinJS framework. Check it out: https://www.reddit.com/r/WPDev/comments/3axpap/slow_performance_with_phonegap_cordova_for/